# Warn when pointer argument used as const but not declared as const

Tags: c, warnings, constants

In legacy code we have many API functions that receive something by non-const pointer and treat it as const (never modify it inside + constness is guaranteed in documentation). I'd like to have this guarantee as "const" in actual function declaration but we have lots of such legacy functions. Is there a compiler (or other code analysis tool) that can warn on functions that receive non const pointer (or reference) argument and treat it as const inside?

Comment: You could change all your pointer declarations to `const` (automating that is left as an exercise) and back out any changes that cause compilation failures.

Comment: Interesting question. Reading the GCC manpage, `-Wsuggest-attribute=const` will suggest "const" type functions; however this will only work on functions that are truly "const" (or "pure"): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html